# How to do the "direct calculation"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

[image]

How I can get the equation (2.25)? What is the calculation? If $|x|$ is the length of the vector, I can't see how to do partial differential with respect to a length?

Can someone help me? It is really important for me. I have been thinking it since last night. Thanks for any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the first equation of that line is a bit confusing. Instead notice that the normal is $x/|x|$, which is the gradient of $f(x)=|x|$, which is in turn because the sphere is the level set of $f$. Therefore

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \nu} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{G(x+tx/|x|) - G(x)}{t}$$

You can in turn calculate this as $\nabla G \cdot (x/|x|)$.

Comment: Thanks! I know it is $\bigtriangledown G*(x/|R|)$ if $x$ is in the boundary. But how to do this calculation to the final poisson kernel? Can you give me some hint? The function is too complicated to calculate and I have spend several hours without getting right answer.